# Cortana Custom Skill - Conversation after Invocation?

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana

Basically I just want to know if there is a way to communicate with my Custom Cortana Skill(which is a bot made with Bot Framework and uses LUIS) after invoking it? At the moment I can Invoke my skill using 'tell bot hi' or even just 'tell bot' which works however, each time i want to communicate with my bot I have to re-invoke the skill(doesn't allow user to continue to message/speak to skill, in essence - only allows a user to send 1 statement to the skill each time which is pointless for a speech bot. Especially since i have an SMS OTP login authentication, which cannot work if the user can't even enter the required information. I understand that the 'utterance' is required to get a reply from my skill, but is there no way to call my skill in Cortana similar to the way it is accessed using a Bot Emulator or Facebook?

Comment: Can you share your bot code that demonstrates the issue? It's hard to say what the problem is without looking at the bot code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out why there was an issue for me. I invoked my skill via typing, which then brought up my skill and a response but didn't allow me to continue speaking to it after that(the text box was greyed out). When i invoked my skill via speech, i was able to continuously communicate with my skill after invocation. So that must be a bug with Cortana at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the skill via typing, Cortana assumes that you do not want to speak to it so it doesn’t read out the message and it doesn’t keep the mic open. Hope that helps.